# Problem on measurement of spin of an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

I came across a problem which reads:
"An electron is initially found to have z-component of spin=+h/4π. Then a measurement of component of its spin along x-direction is carried out but the result is not recorded. Finally, a measurement of its spin along z-direction is carried out. What is the probability of getting spin=+h/4π?"
My problem is what to do when a operator is applied but result is not recorded and what will be final result?

[image: in case you didn't understand the question, here is a picture.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A “measurement” is something that collapses the wavefunction to an eigenstate of the operator corresponding to the quantity being measured, regardless of whether the result of that measurement gets recorded or not.